# Is it possible to use both C# and VB.NET in Custom Code?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Can you do coding in SSRS in C#? Or, put in another way: can you configure SSRS to use either VB.NET or C# for custom code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by Custom Code. As far as I know:

- [Embedded code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155798%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) in the report has to be VB
- [Custom Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153561%28v=sql.100%29) are just .NET assemblies and can be either

Comment: there's only one way to put in custom code and that's .NET as stated in the SSRS report properties.  Yea great, just what I was hoping not, ONLY VB.NET  sh**

Comment: @PositiveGuy: Not only that, but in .NET Core, Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings has almost nothing implemented, if the method stub exists at all.